# Jquery remove class failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a upload script that is adding and extra upload button (that works fine), but the remove button does not work

```
var i = $("#AddFileInputBox div").size() + 1;
$("#AddMoreFileBox").click(function () {
    event.returnValue = false;
    if(i < MaxFileInputs)
    {
        $('<span><input type="file" id="fileInputBox" size="20" name="file[]" class="addedInput" value=""/><a href="#" class="removeclass small2"><img src="images/close_icon.gif" border="0" /></a></span>').appendTo(FileInputsHolder);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){
    event.returnValue = false;
    if( i > 1 ) {
            $(this).parents('span').remove();i--;
    }

});
```

Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

line: 113, which is

```
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Did you try `$(".removeclass").on("click", function(e){` ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: make sure you have latest version of jquery ..jquery 1.7+

Comment: Did I just see `size()`, my eyes are burning ..........

Comment: and `event.returnValue` without passing the event, was this code written for IE only ?

Comment: $(".removeclass").on("click", function(e){ did not work

Comment: `event.returnValue` should be removed. If you want to pass the `event` Object then you need to pass it into your function with the same variable name, but you don't need to pass it at all, because you are not using the `event` Object. If you want to prevent default behavior you may be able to do that with `event.preventDefault`, or `return false`, but you don't need to in your case.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to update your version of JQuery to at least version 1.7, as that is when [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was introduced. Here is the documentation for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which was introduced in [JQuery version 1.7](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/).

Also important to note is that the [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) method is deprecated as of [JQuery 1.8](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/), please use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

So either use JQuery 1.7, or if you would like to use the newest version of Jquery, replace all instances of `.size()` with `.length`.

[Here is a working copy of your example. (Using JQuery 1.9.1)](http://jsfiddle.net/zf6fU/)

Comment: At least you got three upvotes on a completely wrong answer, the right answer would be just to upgrade jQuery to at least version 1.7 ?

Comment: I do now. Let me take some minutes to revise my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for doubting me @adeneo, I learned something new today too!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with reverting to jquery 1.7 and it worked, thanks for all your help people.

Comment: You don't need to revert to 1.7 Just replace all instances of `.size()` with `.length`